# SQL Azure grant execute permission to stord proc user setup on inital DB server creation

Tags: azure-sql-database

When I setup my SQL Azure DB it asked for me to create a login, which I did. Now I need to give that users execute permission on some stored proc but when I run

`GRANT EXECUTE ON ELMAH_GetErrorsXml TO MyUser;`

I get the error
`Cannot find the user 'MyUser', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.`

If I look under Security -> Users I do not see my user listed I only see `dbo quest INFORMATION_SCHEMA sys`.

Can you programmatically change user settings like this?